# Table TR TD align cell fixed at bottom?

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to get my row/cell that displays "Daily total" to stick to the bottom .. as you can see in my image one is higher than the other because of an extra entry inputted...

[image]

i've tried many different valign and vertical-align but cant figure it out.. maybe someone can help me?

here is the html for that tr/td:

```
echo "<tr><td class=\"daily_total_style\" valign=\"bottom\"><b>Daily Total: " . calcMinutes($dailytotal) . "</b></td></tr>";
```

Comment: you will need to provide more HTML so we understand the structure. Most likely you are using nested tables and the `tr` with he total is not as tall as you believe..

Comment: Your code should work, the `valign="bottom"` do the job as showed here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6mnH/ please check your table height and/or show us your full table html I think the problem is there.

Comment: ok .. its messy and i had to take a lot of content out so some table/td/tr tags are red... http://jsfiddle.net/Xu4A5/4/

Comment: edit your post and add it in there, it's important... also, try to clean it up a little more... by the way, you don't seem to consistently use the different `table` tags which might just be the cause of your issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

much better to use a css rule than attributes

```
<td class=\"daily_total_style\" style=\"vertical-align: text-bottom\">
```

EDIT: it's also better to assign this style to a class and assign also this class to your `td`

---

**CATCHED THE ERROR:**

You are applying valign to inner `td`, not container one.

Your td cointainer have to look like this:

```
<td class="calendar_cell_middle" width="14%" valign="bottom" height="25%">
```

however, valign it's not more supported in HTML5, so try to include it as css. More, avoid this inner tables, are really hard to manage !

Comment: jfiddle, so we can see if there's anything that overwrite the rule

Comment: Your css is wrong, the right one is `vertical-align: bottom;`

Comment: ok .. its messy and i had to take a lot of content out so some table/td/tr tags are red... http://jsfiddle.net/Xu4A5/4/

Comment: ok. I see there's a lot of work to do since html it's not passing the validation so probably it's just a markup issue. You can't have a nested "tr". You can nest table in "td", full tables, not parts or just rows. I'll try to fix the jfiddle...

Comment: Ok done. look for fixed html to this jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xjD3Q/ (last line seems broken, but pass html validation. I edited my post with the right fix (not included in jfiddle)

Comment: thanks for all your time and help.  i know its old code and really messy... i'm in the process of cleaning it all up.  thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following for your `td` in css:

```
td {
    vertical-align:bottom
}
```

Also make sure that you don't forget to add the `table` tags to your code like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="daily_total_style">
            <b>Daily Total 1</b><br />
            <b>Daily Total 2</b><br />
        </td>
        <td class="daily_total_style">
            <b>Daily Total</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You will find a [**fiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4BTa4/3/)

Additionally you may want to review what you have added in your `daily_total_style` css class; something in there might be interfering with your code.

**EDITED:** I updated your fiddle you just created with the above and it works fine: [**check it out here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xu4A5/5/)

Comment: you don't seem to echo the `table` tags, are they actually there on your output somehow? Can you maybe add to your post a little more of the html you're outputting and also the contents of `daily_total_style` in css?

Comment: as noted above, you don't seem to use the `table` tags consistently as I advised in my answer... you'll have to review that, ensure you have the nice accordeon of (at least) `table` - `tr` - `td` (and back) `/td` - `/tr` - `/table` and you should be good to go!

Comment: I just added `vertical-align:bottom` to your fiddle and it works fine: [http://jsfiddle.net/Xu4A5/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/Xu4A5/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can include a blank row between the 1st and last row and then set fixed widths for all the table data, It will make both the tables look more similar to each other if they both have 3 rows